# facing issue with IE10 autocomplete feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am having "username" textbox and when user  tries to do any change on "username" textbox,the submit button has to enable.
I am facing issue when user is trying to autocomplete the "username" textbox. 
This issue occurs only on IE10 but with IE11 it works fine.

Here is my Code snippet:

```
 $("#txtUserName").on("change keyup blur input click", enableDisableLoginButton);
```

HTML

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { id = "txtUserName", placeholder = UserName, style = "width:70%;height:28px", @class = "form-control", accesskey = "U" })
```

The function 'enableDisableLoginButton' is not getting called when user tries with autocomplete.

Can some one suggest how to capture the event for textbox in case of autocomplete.

Comment: and this 'textbox' is ... what? a `<textarea>`? `<input>`? `<div>` with contentEditable?

Comment: I have added the HTML code snippet as well